# ContentDialog disappears when pressing Escape

Tags: c#, uwp, dialog

So I´m using:  `public sealed partial class SynchronizationDialog : ContentDialog`.

I have an UWP app. When I press on a button in the UWP app the `SynchronizationDialog` opens and the app starts to download documents. The progress can be seen in the Dialog.

After the downloads are done the dialog "closes" by using `this.Hide();`

Now my problem is that when I press the `Escape`-key the Dialog disappears. Yet the download is still going and everything works just fine.

How can I prevent the Dialog from disappearing? I tried this:

```
public SynchronizationDialog()
{
    this.InitializeComponent();
    this.Loaded += SynchronizationDialog_Loaded;

    this.Closing += ContentDialog_Closing; //this is what I tried
}

//....

void ContentDialog_Closing(ContentDialog sender, ContentDialogClosingEventArgs args)
{
    bool doNotClose = true;
    if (doNotClose)
    {
        args.Cancel = true;
    }
}
```

The Dialog doesnt disappear this way. But after the download is finished and `this.Hide();` happens the Dialog does not hide. I also cannot cancel the dialog so it stays there till I restart the app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would create a new boolean flag that would indicate if synchronization is still in progress and a custom method that will mark it as `false` and then proceed with `Hide`:

```
private bool _workInProgress = true;

public void FinishWork()
{
   _workInProgress = false;
   this.Hide();
}
```

Now the `Closing` event handler would be updated to the following:

```
void ContentDialog_Closing(ContentDialog sender, ContentDialogClosingEventArgs args)
{
    args.Cancel = _workInProgress;     
}
```

Now instead of `Hide` use the `FinishWork` method when the synchronization is complete.

Comment: ohhh. thats cool. that worked out. thanks. Do I understand it correctly? with 'this.hide()' the ContentDialogClosingEventArgs Event is fired?

Comment: Yes, but the main trick is that we set `args.Cancel` to `_workInProgress` which is `true` while the synchronization is in progress, but we set it to `false` in `FinishWork` which means, `args.Cancel` will not be set and the dialog closing will continue

Answer (score 0):

Use a AppBarButton not a Button to solve the esc. exception error issue.
The Dialog just closes when hitting the esc. key.